# sqlite3.OperationalError: table answers has no column named

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to insert some values into a table. Here's my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  email TEXT NOT NULL,
  key TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE answers (
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `AM - Marketing_Copy` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE questions (
  q_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  skill TEXT NOT NULL,
  question TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

The answers table is actually longer than that, but that should be all that's necessary to help me. An important thing to note is that all the values for questions['skill'] correlate to a column in the answers table.

Here's my python code:

```
def get_questions():
    questions = get_db().execute(
        'SELECT skill, question FROM questions'
    )
    return questions

def other():
    db = get_db()
    user = db.execute(
        'SELECT * FROM user WHERE key = ?', (key,)
        ).fetchone()
    questions = get_questions()
    string = "user_id, "
    string += ", ".join("".join(["`",question['skill'],"`"]) for question in questions)
    tuple1 = [user['id']]
    tuple1.append(-1 for i in range(len(questions.fetchall())))
    tuple1 = tuple(tuple1)
    db.execute(
        'INSERT INTO answers ({}) VALUES ({})'.format(string, ", ".join("?" for i in range(len(tuple1)))),
        tuple1
    )
```

Basically the idea is that it will get all the questions from the questions table, and create a string out of all the question['skill'] values, which all correlate to column names in the answers table. It will then insert a value of -1 into each column, except user_id (the first column), where it will insert the actual user id. The error I'm currently getting is:

sqlite3.OperationalError: table answers has no column named AM - Marketing_Copy

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Anyone else know why?

Comment: I tried something as similar as I could, and I couldn't reproduce the error. It would help if you came up with a more minimal example, by giving us the actual query that is failing. You would also need to omit the same columns as you did in the table definition, so we can reproduce it.

Comment: I'll upload it tomorrow (it's late where I am), thanks for the help :)

Comment: So it turns out I accidentally put a space in the skill when there was no space in the column... haha. Code works perfectly. Thanks for offering your help.